# What does "the pebble-dashed walls of number two" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ... He had sensed rather than heard it: someone or something was standing in the narrow gap between the garage and the fence behind him.
>   Harry squinted at the black alleyway.
>   If only it would move, then he'd know whether it was just a stray cat
>   or – something else.
>
> 'Lumos,' Harry muttered, and a light appeared at the end of his wand,
>   almost dazzling him.
>   He held it high over his head, and ***the pebble-dashed walls of number
>   two*** suddenly sparkled;
>   the garage door gleamed, and between them, Harry saw, quite distinctly, the hulking outline of something very big, with wide, gleaming eyes.

As the title says, I don't understand "**the pebble-dashed walls of number two**". Is 'number two' the address number of someone's house or something?

-- From Harry Potter.

Comment: When quoting from a work, best to keep the original  paragraph structure, rather than break the paragraph up into pieces  like that. At least I assume "Harry squinted at the black alleyway." is not its own paragraph in the original.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Houses in British streets are commonly given numbers, even numbers on one side, and odd numbers on the other. Number two would be the lowest-numbered house on the even numbered side of the street. A pebble-dashed wall is one which has been first coated with a thin layer of concrete, and while this is still wet, sprayed with small pebbles which stick to the concrete.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also do me a little more favor to explain "*between them*"? I don't understand what 'them' refers to?

Comment: Between Harry, the garage of number 2 and the fence, in a narrow alleyway

Comment: @JamesK, "the number two" is "the garage"? I thought "the number two" and "the garage" are different buildings.

Comment: **(1) the pebble-dashed walls of number two** suddenly sparkled;  **(2) the garage door** gleamed, and **between them Harry saw**, quite distinctly, the hulking outline of something very big...

Comment: Actually I think "between" is rather ambiguous (and not very well expressed) But all we really need to know is that something big, black and scary is watching Harry from the shadows.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I had a hard time to picture the locations from this part of the book. First, Harry collapsed onto a low wall in Magnolia Crescent street. ... later stating there is something watching him standing in the narrow gap between the garage and the fence behind him. ... Harry squinted at the black alleyway(I think the alleyway refers to Magnolia Crescent) and there were number two building, a garage and the gutter. All messed up. I'm still not clear how the things have been located.

Comment: JK Rowling has often been criticised for her careless writing. [Guardian blog](https://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2007/jul/17/harrypottersbigconisthep)

Comment: It's possible that *between them* refers back to the garage and fence in the first sentence quoted from the passage in OP.

Comment: Like I said. Careless. The notion that someone who sells lots of books is a great, or even a good writer, is dispelled by JK Rowling (If Mickey Spillane had not already done that).